# Movie about a spacecraft that plays musical notes

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, spaceship

Movie where a man builds a dirt mountain in his house and contacts a spacecraft that plays musical notes.

Comment: This is [*Close Encounters of the Third Kind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_Encounters_of_the_Third_Kind).

Comment: dirt? dirt?  **_mashed potatos!!_** - this is iconic - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdkS0TgEG30

Comment: @davidbak Oh, he fumbled with mashed potatoes and other mediums, but eventually he went hardcore and did an amazing mock-up of dirt (and other materials) that filled his living room.

Comment: Heavy sigh... reminds me of "Movie about a boy, two men, a robot and a war."

Comment: @davidbak - That's [the wrong link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGjjCuaCrgI).

Comment: @jeffronicus: Terminator 2? :D

Comment: Fun fact: a lot of the special effects developed for this movie were re-used to create the city scenes in Bladerunner

Comment: Is it ok to ask about such well known things?  I think I'll just go ask for the name of a movie I saw a while back with laser swords....

Comment: @JK. It's a sad fact that the young don't know things that used to be well known. Let's remind ourselves that it's possible to have people on this site who were actually not yet born when this site was first started. Stackoverflow (not necessarily SF.stackexchange) is now 15 years old and we have people younger than that asking questions.

Comment: @JK. - [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1053/)

Comment: @slebetman I wouldn't expect anyone under 15 to know much about this movie, but I'm in my 40s and I've also never seen it. I had no idea that Homer Simpson sculpting a circus tent from mashed potatoes was a reference to anything until today!

Comment: I saw Aaron Sorkin being interviewed about writing the revival of "Camelot". The interviewer asked him if his Merlin was modeled after Obi-Wan Kenobi. Sorkin admitted he's never seen any of the Star Wars movies. (To me, it would make more sense to ask George Lucas the opposite question.)

Comment: Honourable mention for The Clangers https://clangers.com/media/pages/modules/history/2971472933-1647973645/history06-1000x260.jpg

Answer (score 33):

Since I didn't find a question for this to be duplicate of, I'm going to post this as an answer.  The movie you're looking for is the Spielberg classic [*Close Encounters of the Third Kind*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075860/) (1977).

Quoting parts of the [plot summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_Encounters_of_the_Third_Kind#Plot):

> At a rural home outside Muncie, Indiana, three-year-old Barry Guiler wakes to find his toys operating on their own. He starts to follow something outside, forcing his mother, Jillian, to chase after him. Large-scale power outages begin rolling through the area, forcing electrician Roy Neary to investigate. While he gets his bearings, **Roy experiences a close encounter with a UFO**, and when it flies over his truck, it lightly burns the side of his face with its lights. The UFO takes off with three others in the sky, as Roy and three police cars give chase. The spacecraft fly off into the night sky but the metaphysical experience leaves Roy mesmerized. He becomes fascinated by UFOs to the dismay of his wife, Ronnie. **He obsesses over subliminal images of a mountain shape, often making models of it. Jillian meanwhile also becomes obsessed, sketching the unique mountain image**. Soon after, she is terrorized in her home by a UFO which descends from the clouds. She fights off violent attempts by the UFO and unseen beings to enter the home, but in the chaos, Barry is abducted.
>
> Lacombe, Laughlin, and a group of United Nations experts continue to investigate increasing UFO activity and strange, related occurrences. Witnesses in Dharamsala, Northern India report that **the UFOs make distinctive sounds: a five-tone musical phrase in a pentatonic scale**. Scientists broadcast the phrase to outer space, but are mystified by the response. This is a seemingly meaningless series of numbers (104 44 30 40 36 10) repeated until Laughlin, with his background in cartography, recognizes it as a set of geographical coordinates, which point to Devils Tower near Moorcroft, Wyoming. Lacombe and the U.S. military converge on Wyoming. The United States Army evacuates the area, planting false reports in the media that a train wreck has spilled a toxic nerve gas, while actually preparing a secret landing zone for the UFOs and their occupants.

Comment: I'm amazed no-one has asked this before, bit then it is a very well known movie and quite easily searchable.

Comment: @bob1 That is completely true.  It was also 45 years ago, so there are a lot of people who may never have seen it.

Comment: The amazing part about this sequence is that it's meant to look like they're playing some kind of synthesizer, but the synthesizers available in the 70's weren't up to the task, so they just used regular old acoustic instruments, I believe an oboe and a tuba?

Comment: @DavidW "It was also 45 years ago, so there are a lot of people who may never have seen it" I work with people - grown adults! - who have never seen _or even heard of_ "The Blues Brothers" or "Gremlins". They call themselves "adults" but they simply haven't lived.